# How to GET arguments, like HTML GET, in node.js - Why the code is not executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi i'm trying to GET argument from a node.js page called `RegistroScuola.js`, this page pass an argument, `idAlunno` to the page `Voti.js` and in this page I want to GET the argument passed. How to do? I tried to use express but the code are not executed, I'm talking about:

```
app.get('/registroScuola.js',function(request, response){
    console.log("request.idAlunno="+request.idAlunno);
    idAlunno = request.idAlunno;
});
```

this is the whole code:

```
const http = require('http');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'andrea',
  password: '******',
  database: 'scuola',
  charset: 'utf8'
});

//html string that will be send to browser
var reo ='<html><head><title>Voti</title></head><body><h1>Voti</h1>{${table}}</body></html>';

var express = require("express");
var app = express();

let idAlunno=0;

var sqlAlunni ='SELECT * FROM registro_voti WHERE id_alunno =';

//let sqlAlunni ='SELECT * FROM registro_voti WHERE id_alunno ="'+idAlunno+'"';
idAlunno = '"'+idAlunno+'"';
console.log("idAlunno="+idAlunno);

function setResHtml(sql, cb){
      pool.getConnection((err, con)=>{
        if(err) throw err;

        app.get('/registroScuola.js',function(request, response){
            console.log("request.idAlunno="+request.idAlunno);
            idAlunno = request.idAlunno;
        });

        con.query(sql+con.escape(idAlunno), (err, res, cols)=>{
          if(err) throw err;

          var rows = ''; //to store html rows

          //create html table with data from res.
          for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
              rows += `<tr><td style="cursor:pointer">${res[i].voto}</td></tr>`;
          }

          var table = `<table border="1" id="table1"><tr><th>Voto</th></tr>${rows}</table>`;

          con.release();       

          return cb(table);
        });
      });
    }

//create the server for browser access
const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
  setResHtml(sqlAlunni, resql=>{
    reo = reo.replace('{${table}}', resql);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    res.write(reo, 'utf-8');
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(8081);
```

Comment: Is it passed as a query or as a param?

Comment: param. html+= `<script>
        function visualizzaVoti() { var idAlunno = document.getElementById("comboBox").value;
        var Alunno = document.getElementById("comboBox").text;
        window.open("http://localhost:8081/idAlunno="+idAlunno, "Voti alunno"+ Alunno);}
       </script>`

Comment: try request.params

Comment: the code is not executed

Comment: What code is not executed? How can you tell?

Comment: Hi, the first code in my post, nothing is logged.(app.get)